# Accessing Methods on Web API after being authenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am having trouble understanding how i can use my api to login as a user and then have access to specific methods:

```
 public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage Response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            // check if all required fields are set
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // authenticate user
                var success = Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password);

                if (success)
                {
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                            model.UserName,
                            DateTime.UtcNow,
                            DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                            true,
                            "Api ticket",
                            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

                    //Encrypt the ticket.
                    string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

                    //Create the cookie.
                    CookieHeaderValue mycookie = new CookieHeaderValue(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);

                    // Set the cookie's expiration time to the tickets expiration time
                    if (ticket.IsPersistent)
                        mycookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;


                    Response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { mycookie });


                    return Response;
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            //return View(model);
            return Response;
        }
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            return User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
```

I am using Fiddler, and I post to this method with my json object including my username and password.  If I debug, everything goes in successfully and i get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=4FDA2F2D23381CD0C9AD901BB8A9FE808254502F3BB9442CF80B67F318E7000A1C8B395A97616DBE893317072957F7E1790D81F8648C8472EA80AE2A5E60BE81F08F8C0BF07F2F1EB8E1C661EE56FB61FEA7FCD4D7AABF2718B58690D4D82B049B16126D44368429331D8E3138D533D4; expires=Wed, 27 Feb 2013 21:45:48 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcUHJvamVjdHNcRGVjaXNpb25NYWtlclxEZWNpc2lvbk1ha2VyXGFwaVx1c2Vyc1w=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 26 Feb 2013 21:45:48 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

From here, how can I access my `Get()` method without it returning a 401 Unauthorized error?  I make sure to add the following header to my GET:

`Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=4FDA2F2D23381CD0C9AD901BB8A9FE808254502F3BB9442CF80B67F318E7000A1C8B395A97616DBE893317072957F7E1790D81F8648C8472EA80AE2A5E60BE81F08F8C0BF07F2F1EB8E1C661EE56FB61FEA7FCD4D7AABF2718B58690D4D82B049B16126D44368429331D8E3138D533D4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cookies for a restful API access is not the best approach. It would be better to implement security using tokens which are sent with Authorization attributes. Here's an excellent [`blog post`](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/) illustrating how you could write a custom action filters to implement this.

Comment: What you mean is use Form Authentication is not the best approach?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I mean.